# Как найти отсутствующие индексы в MS SQL Server 2000?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Собственно, в интернете нашёл скрипты для поиска отсутствующих индексов для версий начиная с 2005. Даже встречал скрипты которые мне показали бы самые долгие запросы с отсутствующими индексами, и ещё множество интересных, но всё это не для 2000. Совсем не хочется проверять каждый запрос и каждую процедуру или функцию.

Answer (score 0):

В 2000 есть инструмент Index Tunning Wizard